# Post localhost:3000/api/users 404 not found

Tags: javascript, http-status-code-404, mern

Trying to set up authentication that pops up an error that changes depending on what is wrong when trying to register. can't figure out why I'm getting this error. Any help would be greatly appreciated

I included a picture of the error and the code to help figure out what's going on. I can get the alert to pop up when passwords that don't match up but I can't get it to work for the other errors of no name, no email, and no passwords

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jQyOH.png)

ACTION

```
import axios from 'axios'
import { setAlert } from './alert'
import { REGISTER_SUCCESS, REGISTER_FAIL } from './types'

export const register = ({ name, email, password }) => async dispatch => {
  const config = {
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
  }
  const body = JSON.stringify({ name, email, password })
  try {
    const res = await axios.post('/api/users', body, config)
    dispatch({
      type: REGISTER_SUCCESS,
      payload: res.data
    })
  } catch (err) {
    const errors = err.response.data.errors
    if (errors) {
      errors.forEach(error => dispatch(setAlert(error.msg, 'danger')))
    }
    dispatch({
      type: REGISTER_FAIL
    })
  }
}
```

ALERT

```
// bring in set types
import { SET_ALERT, REMOVE_ALERT } from '../actions/types'

// set initial state as empty
const initialState = []

// export fucntion that takes in that that is initial state and an action
export default function something (state = initialState, action) {
  // destructure action
  const { type, payload } = action
  // evaluate actions based on their type
  switch (type) {
    // in case of set alert
    case SET_ALERT:
      // copy into array, alert that is given to us in state, and set alert with action.payload
      return [...state, payload]
    case REMOVE_ALERT:
      // use filter to find a specific alert and see if alert id is NOT equal to the alert in the payload (filter through all alerts except the one that matches the payload)
      return state.filter(alert => alert.id !== payload)
      // default to simply returning the state
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

REGSITER

```
import React, { Fragment, useState } from 'react'
// bring in connect
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
// bring in setAlert
import { setAlert } from '../../actions/alert'
import { register } from '../../actions/auth'
// bring in proptypes
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'

const Register = ({ setAlert, register }) => {
  // the object full of values is formData, function to update state(formData) is setform data
  const [ formData, setFormData ] = useState({
    // default state values
    name: '',
    email: '',
    password: '',
    password2: ''
  })

  // destructure formData
  const { name, email, password, password2 } = formData
  // the on chage at the level of the individual form input will call the onChange function that will call setFormData which
  // changes the value based on the name of the target and the value inputed to the target
  const onChange = e => setFormData({ ...formData, [e.target.name]: e.target.value })

  // on submit funciton arrow function
  const onSubmit = e => {
    // prevent lock
    e.preventDefault()
    // if password does not match password too, log error message the alert is the class for the styling
    if (password !== password2) {
      setAlert('passwords do not match', 'danger')
      // if it does work, log the data in the state
    } else {
      register({ name, email, password })
    }
  }

  // adding value={variable} asociates the variable with the current state, the on change causes the state to be updated
  return (
    <Fragment>
      <h1> Registration </h1>
      <p> Create your account </p>
      <form onSubmit={e => onSubmit(e)}>
        <div>
          <input
            type='text'
            placeholder='Name'
            name='name'
            value={name}
            onChange={e => onChange(e)}
          />
        </div>
        <div>
          <input
            type='email'
            placeholder='Email Address'
            name='email'
            value={email}
            onChange={e => onChange(e)}
          />
        </div>
        <div>
          <input
            type='password'
            placeholder='Password'
            name='password'
            minLength='6'
            value={password}
            onChange={e => onChange(e)}
          />
        </div>
        <div>
          <input
            type='password'
            placeholder='Confirm Password'
            name='password2'
            minLength='6'
            value={password2}
            onChange={e => onChange(e)}
          />
        </div>
        <div>
          <input type='submit' value='Register' />
        </div>
        <p>
            Already have an account?
          <a href='/login' > Login </a>
        </p>
      </form>
    </Fragment>
  )
}
// proptype regis
Register.propTypes = {
  setAlert: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  register: PropTypes.func.isRequired
}

// export using connect the null is temporar and this lets us pass setAlert (actions we want to use from props) State, object with actions we want to use
export default connect(null, { setAlert, register })(Register)
```

AUTH API

```
// bring in express
const express = require('express')

// bring in router
const router = express.Router()
// Bring in middleware
const auth = require('../../middleware/auth')
// bring in user model
const User = require('../../models/Users')
// bring in validator
const { check, validationResult } = require('express-validator')
// Bring in JWT
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken')
// Bring in secret
const config = require('config')
// Bring in Bcrypt
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs')

// @Route:         Get api/auth
// @Description:   Test route
// @access:        Public

// when using path api/auth/ send "auth route" response *add auth to make the route protected by middleware* make it asynch
router.get('/', auth, async (req, res) => {
  // when accessing this get request
  try {
    // search user model by id and excldue the password
    const user = await User.findById(req.user.id).select('-password')
    // respond with the information taken from the database tied to the selected id
    res.json(user)
    // if unable to find by id
  } catch (err) {
    // log error
    console.error(err.message)
    // send error code 500 and server error dialogue
    res.status(500).send('server error')
  }
})

// @Route:         Post api/auth
// @Description:   Authenticate user and get token
// @access:        Public

// get api/users/ will send response of user route
router.post(
  '/',
  // adds secondary requirement of running checks
  [
    // check email is valid
    check('email', 'Please Include Valid Email').isEmail(),
    // check email is present
    check('password', 'Password is requried').exists()
  ],

  // asynch because is its what is commonly used
  async (req, res) => {
    // set errors to result from validation
    const errors = validationResult(req)
    // if not errors is empty
    if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
      // reutn the status 400 and an json array that shows the error.
      return res.status(400).json({ errors: errors.array() })
    }
    // bring in user information, destructure req.body into email, and password for ease of use
    const { email, password } = req.body

    try {
      // check if user exists
      // look at response to find email
      let user = await User.findOne({ email })
      // if user is not found
      if (!user) {
        // send error status and show invalid crednetials
        return res.status(400).json({ errors: [{ msg: 'Invalid Credentials' }] })
      }

      // check that password matches to the user by comparing the plain text password to the encrypted password
      const isMatch = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password)
      // if it does not match then throw 400 status and show invalid credential message
      if (!isMatch) {
        // 400 response and jsonformat response of invalid credentials
        return res.status(400).json({ errors: [{ Msg: 'Invalid crednetials ' }] })
      }
      // return jsonwebtoken
      // create payload to use with jwt
      const payload = {
        // look at saved user
        user: {
          // pull out promised user.id
          id: user.id
        }
      }
      // jwt sign
      // sign with payload and with jwttoken pulled from default.json
      jwt.sign(
        payload,
        // configures the jwt token
        config.get('jwtSecret'),
        // expires in an hour
        { expiresIn: 3600 },
        // if an error
        (err, token) => {
          // throw the error
          if (err) throw err
          // response with the token
          res.send({ token })
          // console.log(token)
        }
      )
    } catch (err) {
      // console the error message
      console.error(err.message)
      // send 500 status with server error text
      res.status(500).send('server error')
    }

    console.log('something was posted')
  })

// export route to be used in other parts of the program
module.exports = router
```

USER ROUTE

```
// brining in express
const express = require('express')
// bring in router
const router = express.Router()
// bring in validator
const { check, validationResult } = require('express-validator')
// bring in user model
const User = require('../../models/Users')
// Bring in Bcrypt
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs')
// Bring in JWT
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken')
// Bring in secret
const config = require('config')
// @Route:         Get api/users
// @Description:   Test route
// @access:        Public

// get api/users/ will send response of user route
// router.get('/', (req, res) => res.send('User Route'))

// @Route:         Post api/users
// @Description:   Register User
// @access:        Public

// get api/users/ will send response of user route
router.post('/',
// adds secondary requirement of running checks
  [
    console.log('fart'),
    // check to make sure a name is present (that its not empty)
    check('name', 'Name is required')
      .not()
      .isEmpty(),
    // check email is valid
    check('email', 'Please Include Valid Email').isEmail(),
    // check email has min 6 char
    check('password', 'Please enter a password with 6 Character minimum').isLength({ min: 6 })
  ],

  // asynch because is its what is commonly used
  async (req, res) => {
    // set errors to result from validation
    const errors = validationResult(req)
    // if not errors is empty
    if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
      // reutn the status 400 and an json array that shows the error.
      return res.status(400).json({ errors: errors.array() })
    }
    // bring in user information, destructure req.body into name, email, and password for ease of use
    const { name, email, password } = req.body

    try {
      // check if user exists
      // look at response to find email
      let user = await User.findOne({ email })
      // if user already exists
      if (user) {
        // send error status and show user already exists message on client
        return res.status(400).json({ errors: [{ msg: 'user already exists' }] })
      }

      // creates new user
      user = new User({
        name,
        email,
        password
      })

      // encrypt password
      // generates salt from bycrpt promise
      const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10)
      // hashes password from newly created user and sets it to user.password
      user.password = await bcrypt.hash(password, salt)
      // save user use await since it leaves a promise
      await user.save()

      // return jsonwebtoken
      // create payload to use with jwt
      const payload = {
        // look at saved user
        user: {
          // pull out promised user.id
          id: user.id
        }
      }
      // jwt sign
      // sign with payload and with jwttoken pulled from default.json
      jwt.sign(
        payload,
        // configures the jwt token
        config.get('jwtSecret'),
        // expires in an hour
        { expiresIn: 3600 },
        // if an error
        (err, token) => {
          // throw the error
          if (err) throw err
          // response with the token
          res.send({ token })
          // console.log(token)
        }
      )
    } catch (err) {
      // console the error message
      console.error(err.message)
      // send 500 status with server error text
      res.status(500).send('server error')
    }

    console.log('something was posted')
  })

// exporting the route to be used in other parts of the program
module.exports = router
```

SERVER

```
/* requre express */
const express = require('express')

// require the connectDB function from db.js
const connectDB = require('./config/db')

/* create app that uses express */
const app = express()

// Connect Database
connectDB()

// initialize middleware
app.use(express.json({ extended: false }))

/* Default to port 5000 */
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000

/* Check to make sure API is running */
app.get('/', (req, res) => res.send('API is Running'))

// Define routes

// make /api/users pertain to the user.js file so that we can use any routes that start with "/"
// when using /api/users we are really using './routes/api/users'
app.use('/api/users', require('./routes/api/users'))

// make /api/users pertain to the user.js file so that we can use any routes that start with "/"
// when using /api/users we are really using './routes/api/users'
app.use('/api/auth', require('./routes/api/auth'))

/* Listen for Server starting and output the port it started on */
app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`server started on port ${PORT}`))
```

Comment: Is your api server running on port 3000? I assume its not, as this is where the react dev server is runnint at.

Comment: my api is running on port 5000, im not sure how change the requests from being on port 3000 to being on port 5000

Comment: `axios.post('http://localhost:5000/api/users'`

Answer (score 0):

Your API server is running on default port 5000 over here. If you have not provided PORT=3000 as environment variable, server is running on port 5000.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I'm having trouble because if I switch the port to 3000, I have both the front end and the back end running on the same port. is there a way for me to change the port that the post requests are being made to?

Comment: @LuisErnestoRivasVillacorta didn't undestand your question. You want to run server on different port than 3000?

Answer (score 0):

Your port for the server is 5000 (localhost:5000) and your axios request is hitting  localhost:3000.

You can change your express port to 3000 by replacing

`const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000`

to

```
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000
```

in your server file.

Then, open `package.json` file of your react-app and modify the "start" script from

```
"start": "react-scripts start"
```

to

```
"start": "PORT=8000 react-scripts start"
```

This will make your react app run on port 8000 and your server run on port 3000.

**Note:** you can change the port to your liking on either side (server or front-end)